# Listview repeats data on subsequent lines

Tags: android, listview, xamarin, duplicates

I have a layout with some buttons and a list view. One of the buttons adds a record to an SQLite database. Another button displays the records in the listview - perhaps 1, 2 or more, say 3 depending on how many times I press the first button.
However, when I press the button to display the records in the listview and scroll down the listview, the same record(s) pop up in lower rows, separated usually by blank rows so that row 6 starts the list again. When I scroll to the bottom and up again, more unwanted records appear on lower lines. Each populated row has a 'valid' record in it, just too many of the same.
When I press the button which re-displays the records in the list view, the view reverts to normal until I scroll down again.
If I reduce the height of the list view, then the repeats start at row 5 not row 6.
Code attached. First, the button in MainActivity which populates the listview:

```
        //ShowRecordsInListView
    Button button5 = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button5_ID);
    button5.Click += delegate
    {

        try
        {
            //Set up the db connection:
            var db = new SQLiteConnection(dbPath);

            //Set up a table:
            db.CreateTable<FieldNamesInTable2>();

            //Get these items from the database and populate the array:
            FieldNamesInTable2[] myRecords = new FieldNamesInTable2[30];
            var table = db.Table<FieldNamesInTable2>();

            int count = 0;
            foreach (var item in table)
            {
                myRecords[count] = item;
                count++;
            }

            //Get ListView:
            var lv = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.recordsListView_ID);
            lv.Adapter = new HomeScreenAdaptor(this, myRecords);

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e);
            Toast.MakeText(this, e.Message, ToastLength.Long).Show();
        }

    };
```

Note the line:
**lv.Adapter = new HomeScreenAdaptor(this, myRecords);**

The top section of code from MainActivity:

```
    namespace Database2.Droid
{
    [Activity(Label = "Database2", Icon = "@mipmap/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
    {       

        //Path string for database file:
        string dbPath = Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "dbDatabase.db3");

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {

            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Database2Layout);
```

...etc.

The list view is actually populated from HomeScreenAdaptor.cs as below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;

namespace Database2.Droid
{

    class HomeScreenAdaptor : BaseAdapter<FieldNamesInTable2>
    //ListView: - this one uses HomeScreenAdapter but has a bug in it which is either it crashes if there are fewer than 6 items, or it repeats
    //randomly with spaces between repeats of the same data lower in the listview.
    {
        FieldNamesInTable2[] myRecords;
        Activity context;

        public HomeScreenAdaptor(Activity context, FieldNamesInTable2[] records) : base()
        {
            this.myRecords = records;
            this.context = context;
        }

        //You need to override 4 attributes:
        public override long GetItemId(int position)
        {
            return position;

        }

        public override FieldNamesInTable2 this[int position]
        {
            get
            {
                return myRecords[position];
            }
        }

        public override int Count
        {
            get
            {
                return myRecords.Length;
            }
        }

        public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {

            //Reuse a row if one becomes available.
            View view = convertView;
            try
            {
                if (view == null)
                {
                    //See Xamarin documentation 'Built-in Row Views' will show you the different types of views - simple, selectable, checkboxes, highlightable, with pictures etc.
                    view = context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, null);
                }
                //Weird alert!! - Text1 exists
                view.FindViewById<TextView>(Android.Resource.Id.Text1).Text = myRecords[position].ToString();
                //Text1 is used by the listview to populate each row.

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e);
                return view;
            }
            return view;

        }
    }
}
```

The try catch areas prevent a crash if there are no records or less than 6 records present - this may be crucial!

Any fixes for the repeated rows problem are greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would try a `RecyclerView`, this alone may solve your problem.

view = context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, null);

^ why are you setting `ViewGroup root` to null?? pass in the `parent` param

Comment: It seems that list view is old technology. Being one to try to keep up, I'll use RecyclerView instead. Thanks.

Comment: Did recyclerview make a difference?

Comment: Yes - I added the download from nuget then it said 'xamarin recyclerview version conflict detected for xamarin.android.support.compat. reference the package directly from the project to resolve this issue.' So I dug myself deeper around that, updating various items until nothing worked. I've just finished re-installing VS and Xamarin.

Comment: Your suggestion was a good one, I'll try it again when my computer feels up to it. Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure how you have your dependencies set up, but it should be as simple as just adding the recyclerview dependency to your gradle file

Answer (score 0):

try this...i have modified your GetView() method

```
    public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {

        //Reuse a row if one becomes available.
        View view = convertView;
        ViewHolder viewholder;
            if (view == null)
            {
                //See Xamarin documentation 'Built-in Row Views' will show you the different types of views - simple, selectable, checkboxes, highlightable, with pictures etc.
                view = context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, null);

            viewholder=new ViewHolder();
            //Weird alert!! - Text1 exists

            viewholder.text1=(TextView)view.findviewbyid(Android.Resource.Id.Text1);

            //Text1 is used by the listview to populate each row.

            view.setTag(viewholder)
           }else{
                viewholder=(ViewHolder)view.getTag();
           }
           viewholder.text1.setText(myRecords[position]);
        return view;

    }
    private class ViewHolder{
         TextView text1;
    }
```

Comment: It's asking for an assembly reference. Do you know which one that might be? Thanks.